# mongodb dbref java

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb

I am newbie to mpngodb.

I have two collections.

```
 Tenant
 {
 Tenant_ID:123, Tenant_Info:new
 Tenant_ID:456, Tenant_Info:old
 }

 System
 {
  System_ID:768, Tenant_ID:123,System_Info:"check"
 }
```

I need to reference the Tenant collection Tenant_ID with System collection Tenant_ID.

Could anyone help me with the DBREF java code for mongodb to achieve this relationship?

Answer (score 1):

[Database References (DBRefs)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/) are used by convention; they do not correspond to a supported feature in the MongoDB server.

If you want to store a reference to another collection in your document you could do it a few ways:

1) Just save the relevant key for the other collection (in your example the `Tenant_ID` of the related Tenant document wants to be saved as a field in a document in the System collection).

2) Use the [DBRef class](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBRef.html) to construct a reference to the object and then [fetch()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBRef.html#fetch(com.mongodb.DB, com.mongodb.DBObject)) the referenced object.

Based on your example, it looks like the first usage would be more relevant - you appear to be saving the `Tenant_ID` field in your `System` document.  In this case, you can load a System document and use [findOne()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findOne%28com.mongodb.DBObject%29) to retrieve the related Tenant document based on the Tenant_ID (assuming Tenant_ID uniquely identifies a Tenant).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Data MongoDB](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/).